# Cannot run an ASP.NET Core app on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, iis-express

I am working on an application using the ASP.NET Core - I am using latest update for **VS2015** and Windows 10. Now I want to deploy some demo version to some other computer.

How can I host my ASP.NET Core application in IIS Express when there is NO VisualStudio installed on the other side? I downloaded the most recent IIS and Microsoft .NET Core SDK from the Microsoft's website. However, I am still getting this error in the event log:

```
Dynamickou knihovnu C:\Program Files\IIS Express\aspnetcore.dll modulu se nepodařilo načíst. Data obsahují chybu.
```

> *That is in czech "...the aspnetcore.dll is missing..."*.

The error message is definitely right, there is no such file in this folder nor in the x86 version.

Every hint how to fix it contains upgrading VisualStudio toolkit that is not suitable for me since there is no VisualStudio on target machine. If it is important, target machine is running Windows 7 or Server 2012.

Comment: What is the configuration of your website in IIS? Did you check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis. Maybe you are missing the  .NET Core Windows Server Hosting installation

Comment: Martijn: This appears to be tutorial for full IIS only, doesn't? I need to get it working on the IIS Express which is AFIK something different.

Comment: Yes, but you need the ASP.NET Core handler as far as i know to run ASP.NET core sites on IIS Express or IIS and that is included in the Server Hosting Installation.

Comment: Check your project.json. If type = "platform" then you'll need to install server hosting. If you don't want to install then remove the line "type": "platform". It doesn't matter if it is IIS Express or full IIS.

Comment: Microsoft has silently updated the IIS Express shipped in VS if you installed its latest SDK and VS bits. So please only use IIS Express as part of VS and don't attempt to use it separately.

Comment: Might be a stupid question but, why do you even need to use IISExpress without Vs?

Comment: jpgrassi: As I mentioned before - I want to make some "demo deployment". It should be like when I am debugging on my local workstation (ie no authorization/authentication, security policies, etc). I thought it will be easier and more lightweight without full IIS and VS installation.

Comment: @JanDrozen: Just use the full IIS. It's part of every Windows Desktop installation under Software and Features > Features (every Version since at least Vista has it). As long as you don't use it to host production sites you're fine. technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725762(v=ws.11).aspx You just need to install the .NET Core files for IIS (called "Windows Server Hosting" on the .NET Core website)

Comment: @JanDrozen if you're goal is to have a lightweight hosting solution, why not skip IIS all together and use .NET Core's own Kesterel server?